# How can i Enable About menu bar item with Applescript

Tags: applescript

i was wondering how i could enable About MyApplication menu bar item on applescript. Ive tried this

```
 tell application "System Events"
    tell process "MyApp"
        set AboutApplication to {}
        repeat with AboutApplication in AboutApplication
            try
                set frontmost to true
                set AboutApplication to enabled of menu item "About MyApp" of menu "Object" of menu bar item "Object" of menu bar 1
                if activeMenuItem is true then
                end if
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

but im pretty sure its wrong.

Can someone tell me how i could enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with AppleScript.

If you are creating an AppleScriptObjC app, you need to add the appropriate script to the About menu item and use the XCode GUI to enable.

If you are writing a simple script using the Script Editor and want to enable a menu item in another app, it won't make sense, because that app doesn't have any code behind that menu item. Even if you were able to enable the menu item itself, nothing would happen if you clicked it, or a crash at best.

There is no sense in trying this.